# Empty string in mapping(address => string[])

Tags: solidity, mapping, string

I have a

```
mapping(address => string[]).
```

How can I check if, given an address and a position of the array string[] corresponding at that address, it exists a value in that position or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well, you just want to know if the index given is valid, i.e not bigger than the array's length.

```
function check_index(address addy, uint256 index) view returns (bool) {
    return (my_mapping[addy].length > index);
}
```